# How can I delete/replace emoji on input?

Tags: jquery, emoji

I have the problem with emoji. After I type emoji in input and save the form, than I see that most of emoji look like '?' question mark.

[image]

[image]

Is there some jquery function that will delete or replace emoji on 'input' and 'paste'?

P.S I'm not working with database and I literally have 0 knowledge how to change database so it could "see" emoji.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You may need to ask the DBA to change the encoding format of the field to UTF8MB4 to save the emoji